# editar linq c# grupos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, linq, linq-to-sql

Comunidad estoy practicando linq tengo un arreglo como el siguiente {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4}

Tengo lo siguiente

```
console.WriteLine("Digite la longitud de la matriz");
            int lon = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] matriz = new int[lon];
            Console.WriteLine("Escriba separando por un (enter) los digitos para validar la cantidad de veces que hay tripletas");
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.Length; i++)
            {
                matriz[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            var consulta = from x in matriz
                           --WHERE(AQUI DEBE IR LA CONDICION PERO NO ENCUENTRO COMO)
                           select x;

            Console.WriteLine("Respuesta de la consulta: ");

            foreach (var i in consulta)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Esto lo estoy haciendo en c# con linq pero no encuentro bien como plantear la logica intente recorriendo el arreglo con un for pero no me funciono.

Agradezco me puedan orientar si es posible.

Muchas gracias comunidad

Comment: Vas a tener que mantener el número previo y el número actual en un par de variables, en otra variable, tener un contador que se reinicie cuando el número actual sea diferente del número anterior, para la primera pasada, inicia el número previo como nulo y te salteas la comparación. Creo que ya tienes todos los ingredientes para intentar algo :D ¡Buena suerte! PD: es innecesario utilizar linq, con un For tradicional la haces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int[] numeros = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 };

var tripletas = (from n in numeros
                 group n by n into grupo
                 select new
                 { 
                     Numero = grupo.Key,
                     Total = grupo.Count() / 3
                 }).Where(t => t.Total > 0).ToList();

foreach (var t in tripletas)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Número: {0}; Total de tripletas: {1}", t.Numero, t.Total);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Haces una consulta **Linq** totalizando la cantidad de veces que aparece determinado número en el arreglo, para lograr esto debes usar la **cláusula group by**. A ese total que obtienes de determinado elemento del arreglo lo divides entre **3**, ya que una tripleta equivale a **3** elementos iguales, esa división es la que te dará el total de tripletas por cada elemento del arreglo. Posteriormente utilizando el **método Where** haces un filtro para obtener los elementos que tienen al menos **1** tripleta. Por último imprimes por cada elemento la cantidad de tripletas que tiene.

**Nota:** Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Actualización**

Ya que mi código anterior no estaba del todo bien ya que no consideraba que los elementos del arreglo no estuvieran consecutivos como me hizo notar @Yussef dejo una nueva respuesta:

```
Dictionary<int, int> diccTripletas = new Dictionary<int, int>();
int[] numeros = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1 };
int num;
int total;

while (numeros.Count() > 0)
{
    num = numeros.ElementAt(0);                
    total = numeros.TakeWhile(n => n == num).Count() / 3;

    if (total > 0)
    {
        diccTripletas[num] = (diccTripletas.ContainsKey(num)) ? 
                              diccTripletas[num] + total : 
                              total;
    }

    numeros = numeros.SkipWhile(n => n == num).ToArray();                  
}

foreach (var d in diccTripletas)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Número: {0}; Tripletas: {1}", d.Key, d.Value); 
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Aquí se hace uso del **método TakeWhile** para ir tomando todos los elementos del arreglo mientras sean iguales a la primera posición del mismo, luego se halla el total de todos estos elementos obtenidos y se divide este total entre **3** obteniendo de esta forma las tripletas halladas hasta el momento para ese elemento del arreglo, posteriormente guardamos en un diccionario para ese elemento la cantidad de tripletas obtenidas hasta el momento para el elemento analizado, siendo la llave del diccionario el elemento del arreglo y su valor la cantidad de tripletas halladas hasta el momento para ese elemento.

Posteriormente usamos el **método SkipWhile** el cual irá saltando elementos del arreglo mientras sean iguales al primer elemento del arreglo(hace lo opuesto al **método TakeWhile**), de esta forma vamos tomando y saltando elementos del arreglo mientras existan elementos en él. Finalmente imprimimos por cada elemento el total de tripletas halladas.

Answer (score 3):

C# tiene una multitud de formas de hacer las cosas, hay veces que es indiferente ocupar lo uno u lo otro, hay otras que es conveniente ocupar una en particular.

```
int[] numeros = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 };

var fin = numeros.Length - 2; //
var agrupados = numeros[..fin].Select((i, a) => new int[] { i, numeros[a+1], numeros[a+2] });
var result = from a in agrupados
                where a[0] == a[1] && a[0] == a[2]
                select a[0];

foreach(var r in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(r); // 1,1,1,1,3
}
```

- Creamos un sub arreglo desde 0 hasta length-2
- Creamos un array de arrays con tripletas
- Con linq verificamos si son iguales

Esto es lo mismo que hacer:

```
int[] numeros = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 };

for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length - 2; i++)
{
    if (numeros[i]== numeros[i+1] && numeros[i] == numeros[i + 2])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Tripleta encontrada:  {numeros[i]} -> posicion : {i},{i + 1},{i + 2}");
    }
}
```

Esto último es mucho más claro y modificable. Por ejemplo, tú dices que {1,1,1,1,1,1} debería generar 2 tripletas y no 4, es decir cuando encuentre una salta 2 casillas, esto con linq es complicado ya que las iteraciones son normalmente secuenciales, quizás exista una forma con alguna agrupación, pero francamente no vale la pena, cuando con un for puedes saltar el índice fácilmente.

```
int[] numeros = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 };

for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length - 2; i++)
{
    if (numeros[i]== numeros[i+1] && numeros[i] == numeros[i + 2])
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Tripleta encontrada:  {numeros[i]} -> posicion : {i},{i + 1},{i + 2}");
        i = i + 2; //saltamos de índice
    }
}
```

Por esta razón hay que elegir la manera adecuada para operar según el contexto, es como el refran:

> Cuando solo tienes un martillo, todos los problemas tienen forma de
> clavo

---

**Update**

En los comentarios me hicieron ver que quizás la respuesta de salida no era la adecuada.

Por lo que presento una combinación con la respuesta de @Japv

```
int[] numeros = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4 };
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < numeros.Length - 2; i++)
{
    if (numeros[i] == numeros[i + 1] && numeros[i] == numeros[i + 2])
    {
        list.Add(numeros[i]);
        i = i + 2; //saltamos de índice
    }
}

var resultado = from a in list
                group a by a into A
                select new { Numero = A.Key, Total = A.Count() };

foreach(var r in resultado)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Número: {0}; Total de tripletas: {1}", r.Numero, r.Total);
}
```

La idea es guardar todas las tripletas individualemente en una Lista, y ahora si usando `linq` la agrupamos y contamos (count) cuantas existen.

Otra opción podría haber sido ocupar un `Dictionary<int,int>` con el Key como el número y value la cantidad de ocurrencias (tripletas). Pero como la idea original era usar Linq, usé un `group by`

Comment: Y si fuera {1,1,1,3,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,1}, es decir tres tripletas de 1s separadas?

Comment: Lo que dije arriba me lo estoy aplicando a mi también

Comment: Saldría:
Tripleta encontrada:  1 -> posicion : 0,1,2  \n
Tripleta encontrada:  1 -> posicion : 5,6,7 \n
Tripleta encontrada:  1 -> posicion : 9,10,11 \n

Comment: Pero no es eso lo que se pide, lo que se debe es devolver el total, es decir el resultado esperado es que se encontraron 3 tripletas de 1s

Comment: @Japv Entiendo que la idea es encontrar 3 número consecutivos repetidos usando Linq, mi respuesta es que es mejor no usar Linq, sino que un `for` de toda la vida. Y doy unos ejemplos, cuyo código final es el algoritmo solicitado. Si el OP necesita el total o no, no tengo idea pero es un asunto menor, el podrá modificar la salida como guste y de acuerdo a sus necesidades. Por otro lado me queda la duda si tus comentarios son a modo de represalia por haber encontrado un error en tu código???

Comment: Para nada, tus respuestas me gustan mucho, pero en este caso específico el op pide que se cuenten las tripletas que aparecen, tú te diste cuenta de que mi respuesta no era óptima y eso me hizo seguir pensando, y encontré esto nuevo y te lo comenté

Comment: @Japv Perfecto, mil disculpas por el mal entendido (preferí preguntar en vez de quedarme con la mala idea en la cabeza)

Comment: Para totalizar como el op quiere pensando así a lo loco se me ocurre una combinación de TakeWhile con SkipWhile y un diccionario donde la llave sea el número y el valor, la cantidad de tripletas del número que se van encontrando

Comment: Se tomaría el primer elemento en una variable, luego TakeWhile hasta que se encuentre un elemento diferente, se hace un count, se divide entre 3, después SkipWhile, y así hasta q se termine

Comment: @Japv jajajaja Yo también estuve un buen rato pensando cómo hacerlo solo con linq, probé con Aggregate y con Zip, pero luego pensé en la utilidad final,  por esa  razón traté de explicar que era un lio casi sin sentido y que es mejor usar un for y punto. De todas maneras como desafío está entretenido

Comment: Hombre yo te doy mi voto, mis saludos!!!